# ¿Como puedo cancelar una subscripción realizada con checkout personalizado?

Tags: api, mercadopago

Busque en la documentación y no encontré como hacerlo.

Tengo que hacer un PUT  a un subscriptionId actualizando el campo status a cancelled?

Answer (score 2):

La forma correcta sería como vos decís, realizando un request *PUT* con el *status* **cancelled**.

Esto lo podes realizar via cURL:

```
curl -X PUT \
    -H 'accept: application/json' \
    -H 'content-type: application/json' \
'https://api.mercadopago.com/v1/subscriptions/SUBSCRIPTION_ID?access_token=ACCESS_TOKEN \
    -d '{"status": "cancelled"}'
```

Una vez cancelado, no es posible reactivar la subscripción, por lo cuál tal vez te sirve más pausarla y reactivarla en caso de necesitarla.

Esto lo podes hacer enviando los *status* **paused** o **authorized** (para reactivarla) en el request anterior.